# How to get Firefox working with Selenium WebDriver on Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to config proxy settings for the `WebDriver` so I have used the following code ....

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http","207.229.122.162");
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 3128); 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "http://www.example.com/");
```

and after performing run on the file I am getting exception like ...

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH.
>
> Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: MAC
>
> System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.6.8',
>
> java.version: '1.6.0_29'
>
> Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

Can anyone help me out regarding how and where to give path to `firefoxprofile()`

Comment: WebDriver cannot find path to binary file of Firefox. Are you sure Firefox is installed?

Comment: @p0deje : Of course it is !! and also i am using it now ...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe you have several options:

Either specify the folder (in which your Firefox binary is) in your PATH system variable - [here's how](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2621/os_x_change_path_environment_variable/).

Or call

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(new File("path/to/your/firefox.exe")), profile);
```

Comment: Also, to avoid having the path hardcoded, you can use some sort of configuration file, for instance [java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

Comment: Hey Slanec thanks for the code !! i tried that and mozilla was opening in windows !! but the problem is when perform operation like selenium.open("dummy.com"); firefox is popping up but giving error like

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Maps.transformValues(Ljava/util/Map;Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/util/Map;

any idea what this exception is for ?

Comment: Try `selenium.open("http://dummy.com");` - that's with the http prefix. Or if you are using WebDriver, then `driver.get("http://dummy.com");`

Comment: Hi @Slanec i using the code 


FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar lib/selenium-server.jar");
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "207.229.122.162");
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 3128);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(new File("C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/Firefox.exe")), profile);
selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "http://www.example.com/");

Comment: and then i am giving 
`selenium.start();
selenium.open("http://dummy.com");`
with prefix , still the error was firing !!
is this the correct way to call ?

Thanks

Comment: Now I will be shooting with blanks, because this is something I am not familiar with. I never needed the `Process p` call, so I _think_ it's redundant. I'd also (just to be sure) add the html prefix to the `new WebDriverBackedSelenium()` call. Otherwise, yes, this is one correct way to do it. The exception you are getting is something inside Selenium that's calling methods and is choking for some unknown reason. I'd check selenium versions and all dependencies - after that, I'm done =/.

Comment: Hi @Slanec , i am  using 
`Process P = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar lib/selenium-server.jar"); `
to start the selenium server !! Is there any other way to start selenium server through java code !!
and the point about adding http prefix , i have done it , but forget to mention above !!
and one more thing is there something different to MAC and windows that once and build the project in windows and run the same in MAC , the selenium server was not starting ??

Comment: On Windows, adding Firefox to PATH didn't solve anything. I made this BAT file, `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Utils\FirefoxPortable\App\firefox\
firefox
node selenium-webdriverjs.ff.js`, and when I run it, Firefox launches, but Selenium still dies with `Could not locate Firefox on the current system`.

Answer (score 12):

For Mac, if you installed FireFox via brew cask, just symbolic link it to /Applications.

```
cd /Applications
ln -s /Users/<your-username>/Applications/Firefox.app Firefox.app
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I need to move Firefox.app from /Users/username/Applications to /Applications

Answer (score 3):

For Mac:

1. Use selenium jar 2.44.0 (make sure selenium server jar is 2.44.0)
2. firefox version 33 (https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/33.0/mac/en-US/)
3. In terminal of Mac, Use this command to create profile for firefox : "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin" -p

   4. while creating the profile, you would see the path of profile with .default, - make note of this for entering the same in code for profile path.
   5. Code would look like this:

String  profilePath="/Users/admin/Library/ApplicationSupport/Firefox/Profiles/4duhjf19.default";

```
                System.out.println("profilePath: "+profilePath);
                File checkProfile = new File(profilePath);
                File[] allFolder = checkProfile.listFiles();
                for (int i = 0; i < allFolder.length; i++) {

                    if (allFolder[i].getName().endsWith(".default")) {
                        profilePath = profilePath + allFolder[i].getName();
                        break;
                    }
                }
FirefoxProfile firefoxprofile1 = new FirefoxProfile(new File(
                        profilePath));
                System.out.println("profile path : " + firefoxprofile1);
                driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxprofile1);
                System.out.println("webdriver FF");
                driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Comment: This the the answer that worked for me. Specifically the `"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin"` part tipped me off, and I was able to run the jar with: `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-23.1.jar -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin"`

Comment: outdated answer

Answer (score 1):

i met this problem before, it's very easy to fix it.

on **Windows**, modify the environment variables , add the `firefox path` to the `PATH` variable.

it's should be similar on **Mac**, just **export** `PATH=/my/firefox/path/bin:$PATH` in your profile file.

Comment: It can also be that FF is installed per-user, rather than system wide

Comment: On Windows, adding Firefox (Portable edition) to PATH didn't solve anything. I made this BAT file, `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Utils\FirefoxPortable\App\firefox\
firefox
node selenium-webdriverjs.ff.js`, and when I run it, Firefox launches, but Selenium still dies with `Could not locate Firefox on the current system`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about on a Mac, but on Windows I resolved this issue.

Make sure you are using the 32 bit version of nunit.  Firefox is a 32 bit browser.

I have a 64 bit windows OS, but Firefox is a 32 bit browser.  I was trying to use the 64 bit version of nunit, which was giving this "Cannot fine firefox binary in PATH" error.  I resolved this by using the 32 bit version of nunit.  Basically, there are two exe files in the nunit folder, nunit.exe and nunit-x86.exe.  If you are getting this "Cannot fine firefox binary in PATH" error, most likely you need to use the 32 bit version of nunit - the Nunit-x86.exe.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS X, I was receiving a WebDriver error like "Could not find Firefox binary (os=macosx)" when attempting to run a script.

I discovered that my problem was that a renamed my Firefox app to "Firefox 22". The WebDriver stuff expected just "Firefox".

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issue obtained because of selenium web driver fail to find the .exe files of Firefox.  Please check whether C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox you have exe file in the location and don’t forget to set environment variable having the java jdk path. 
Source:- http://www.tech4crack.com/solved-cannot-find-firefox-binary-in-path/