# Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

In Selenium Grid I am trying to execute a simple program and I'm getting `Cannot find firefox binary in PATH` though I have added the binary path in my code.
My code and the error are given below.

**Code**

```
package Sample;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
public class sample1 {
     WebDriver driver;
     String  BaseURL,NodeURL;
@BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() throws MalformedURLException {
     BaseURL="www.google.com";
     NodeURL="http://192.168.10.162:5566/wd/hub";
     DesiredCapabilities capa =DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
     capa.setBrowserName("firefox");
     capa.setCapability("binary", "C:\\Users\\praveenraj.d\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
     capa.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
     driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(NodeURL),capa);
  }
   @Test
  public void f() throws InterruptedException {
      driver.get(BaseURL);
      System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
      Thread.sleep(50000);
  }
  @AfterTest
  public void afterTest() {
      driver.quit();
  }
 }
```

**Error**

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\praveenraj.d\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-1233453386\testng-customsuite.xml

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest beforeTest
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: WIN8
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
System info: host: 'IN-IF-WS1-0154', ip: '192.168.10.162', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_07'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
Command duration or timeout: 97 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.31.0', revision: '1bd294d', time: '2013-02-27 20:53:56'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_13'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
    at Sample.sample1.beforeTest(sample1.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:641)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:609)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:335)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:330)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: WIN8
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
System info: host: 'IN-IF-WS1-0154', ip: '192.168.10.162', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_07'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
Build info: version: '2.31.0', revision: '1bd294d', time: '2013-02-27 20:53:56'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_13'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.Executable.<init>(Executable.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.getBinary(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.callConstructor(DefaultDriverFactory.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:170)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest afterTest
SKIPPED: f

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@93b52b: 27 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@3ba002: 22 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@fa930d: 6 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@1f9c5c8: 6 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@197f158: 6 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 4 ms
```

Comment: The fact your log file is mentioning **last year** and two versions makes me believe you've got a little problem with what versions & jar's you've got installed there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: VISTA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723081/cannot-find-firefox-binary-in-path-make-sure-firefox-is-installed-os-appears-t)

Answer (score 32):

```
File pathToBinary = new File("C:\\user\\Programme\\FirefoxPortable\\App\\Firefox\\firefox.exe");
FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();       
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary,firefoxProfile);
```

Answer (score 22):

Another option is to configure the server rather than the test client.

Configure the slave node service so that it knows where the firefox is. Install location can change from node to node, or even need multiple services running on a node to support access to different versions of FF.

```
java -jar "selenium-server-standalone-2.2.0.jar"
 -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="C:\FirefoxCollection\Mozilla Firefox 36.0\firefox.exe"
```

Comment: I'm using Firefox Portable and this solution fixed [the issue](https://github.com/vvo/selenium-standalone/issues/114).

Comment: On a Mac, just use `/Applications/Firefox.app` instead. :)

Comment: Cool searched several for this working solution. Thanks. But I better need this in the .yml file. Do you maybe know how to do this?

Answer (score 21):

Make sure that firefox must install on the default place like ->(c:/Program Files (x86)/mozilla firefox  OR c:/Program Files/mozilla firefox, **note: at the time of firefox installation do not change the path so let it installing in default path**)
If firefox is installed on some other place then selenium show those error.

If you have set your firefox in Systems(Windows) environment variable then either remove it or update it with new firefox version path.

If you want to use Firefox in any other place then use below code:-

As FirefoxProfile is depricated we need to use FirefoxOptions as below:

New Code:

```
File pathBinary = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathBinary);   
DesiredCapabilities desired = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
desired.setCapability(FirefoxOptions.FIREFOX_OPTIONS, options.setBinary(firefoxBinary));
```

The full working code of above code is as below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\Workspace\\demoproject\\src\\lib\\geckodriver.exe");
File pathBinary = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathBinary);   
DesiredCapabilities desired = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
desired.setCapability(FirefoxOptions.FIREFOX_OPTIONS, options.setBinary(firefoxBinary));
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
```

Download geckodriver for firefox from below URL:

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Old Code which will work for old selenium jars versions

```
File pathBinary = new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathBinary);
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();       
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary, firefoxProfile);
```

Comment: this was helpful info, it belongs in a Selenium FAQ.

Comment: What error you are getting ? Are you working on Windows? What is the location of your Firefox in system?

Comment: This constructor is deprecated, using FirefoxOptions is recommended (see answer by MSC). [Documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/Overload_OpenQA_Selenium_Firefox_FirefoxDriver__ctor.htm)

Comment: Thansk Keku .. I have updated new code as you suggested

Answer (score 5):

Did you add firefox to your path after you have started the selenium server? If that is the case selenium will still use old path. The solution is to **tear down** & **restart selenium** so that it will use the **updated Path** environment variable.

To check if firefox is added in your path correctly you can just launch a command line terminal "cmd" and type "firefox" + ENTER there. If firefox starts then everything is alright and restarting selenium server should fix the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue in C# using 64-bit Windows and the 64-bit Firefox browser which doesn't seem to work on Selenium. If you are using the 64-bit browser, try the 32-bit one.

Surprisingly, the 32-bit Firefox browser runs on 64-bit Windows just fine.

Edited to clarify the intent of my post.

Comment: It does provide an answer to the question. If the OP is using the 64-bit Firefox browser, the solution may be to switch to the 32-bit browser.

Answer (score 2):

I've just had this issue without changing PATH.

My PC is Win7, 64-bit system, 
If you are also using 64-bit system, you may want to try:

1. uninstall your current Firefox.
2. install new Firefox under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\" path.

It must be under "Program Files (x86)" NOT "Program Files"

Hope it can help.

Comment: I was banging my head against the wall.  Everything was working fine on my machine and my tester's machine, but on the VM it wasn't even trying to start.  Checked the install path.  Yep.  "Program Files", not "Program Files (x86)".

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `gecko driver` if you are using `firefox v50` and above.

Use the following sample code :

```
File pathToBinary = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\Downloads\\selenium-java-3.0.1\\geckodriver.exe");       
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary,firefoxProfile);
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see the C# anwer to this question here. The trick is to set the BrowserExecutableLocation property on a FirefoxOptions instance, and pass that into the driver constructor:

```
        var opt = new FirefoxOptions
        {
            BrowserExecutableLocation = @"c:\program files\mozilla firefox\firefox.exe"
        };
        var driver = new FirefoxDriver(opt);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is have your grid nodes register the Firefox binary path as part of the node config.  It uses the same capabilities that the client has, but allows you to pick the browser by name and let the node find it.

Please also note that the capability you want is "firefox_binary" and not "binary".  You can see the full list of Firefox capabilities at this wiki page:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities

Comment: This is the right answer.  How else would the Node know where to find the binary on the remote server?

Comment: i cant get u .plz explain

Comment: The capability you're passing is wrong.  You supplied "binary", but it should be "firefox_binary", per the wiki page I linked you to. As a secondary suggestion, your client shouldn't be setting the page.  The grid node should specify the path in its configuration file so the client can just request the Firefox browser and the grid will launch the correct binary.

Answer (score 1):

This issue may be because of the incompatibility of firefox driver and your firefox browser version. Download the latest version of firefox driver which is compatible with the updated Firefox browser version.

Answer (score 1):

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

Put selenium jar file on desktop, go to cmd and run the above command.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to troubleshoot and fix this issue:

**Cause:** This error usually indicates that the tool/script could not find firefox on its default location

Troubleshooting Steps:

Step 1 - Check your firefox is installed on the default location

c:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox

OR

C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox

Step 2 - Copy the path where your firefox.exe file is located

e.g. C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe

Step 3 - Goto System Environment Variables, Select Path and click Edit

Step 4 - Add the location of firefox.exe file. Make sure not to change/delete existing values

Step 4 - Restart IDE

Step 5 - Save and Run the test again

Answer (score 0):

You should change environment variable and add there path to firefox.exe. The same could be done programmatically [How can I set/update PATH variable from within java application on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350663/how-can-i-set-update-path-variable-from-within-java-application-on-windows). I had the same problem on Win8.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to RemoteWebDriver used in code, It tries to invoke firefox browser in node machine, If you have specified firefox binary location in "PATH" environment variable of node machine, It will open firefix browser on executing it from Hub.

Answer (score 0):

I have also face same issue on Windows 10-64 bit OS.

When I am installed firefox on my PC its installed location is 
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" instead of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox", because OS is 64 bit,

So I just copy & paste "Mozilla Firefox" folder in "C:\Program Files (x86)" folder and execute selenium scripts, its work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Katalon_Studio_Windows_64-5.10.1\\configuration\\resources\\drivers\\firefox_win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
        DriverFactory.changeWebDriver(driver)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the solutions lie in simply uninstalling the application and installing it right back. Had a similar problem. Worked in my case. For some weird reason Firefox had not been installed in the default 'Programs' folder. Installed it again and issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **chromeWebDriver**.
latest version of it in [download](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)

code :

```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","yourplace\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use older version of Firefox.
60.0.1
60.0.2
60.1.0
60.2.0
60.2.1
60.2.2
60.3.0
60.4.0
60.5.0
60.5.1
60.5.2
60.6.0
60.6.1
60.6.2
60.6.3
60.7.0
60.7.1
60.7.2
60.8.0
60.9.0

I have used 60.6.3 and issue resolved.