# How to set a driver path of firefoxdriver in selenium

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

Hi I am very new to selenium . So pardon me for any technical mistakes. 
I have a project which works fine for IE. But I need to test using firefox too. Does the project require a pointer towards the driver like IEDriver in case of execution in IE?

Comment: You might want to improve the question somewhat, i.e. what did you do and what went wrong / what happened? (if applicable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to set the driver path for FirefoxDriver.
You can directly use **`WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`**.

However, there are other ways to run selenium in Firefox also, as below:

1- [Using Firefox Profile](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/); 
Used to run selenium in a new user-defined profile with a set of preferences as necessary.

2- [Using Firefox Binary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24891650/4193730); 
 [PS:- Not much Idea on how it works, But this link might help you out]

Comment: For chrome Driver is required?

Comment: I am assuming, you mean setting up of the Driver property. Yes, it is [done for Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13729517/4193730).

Comment: You actually NEED to do so if bin is not in PATH

Comment: True.. This answer was for an older version of selenium. Now, we need to set up system property from Selenium 3 as geckodriver is in play for Firefox browser

Answer (score 3):

In my enviroment I set the property -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="C:\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"

Answer (score 1):

For testing with `FireFox` you can directly use `driver = new FirefoxDriver()` or you can download selenium driver for ie from [this link](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) and set path property as stated below.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "pathToTheIEDriver");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Answer (score 1):

If we want to run the test case of Firefox then we need GeckoDriver. Use below link for downloading the latest geckodriver: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Save the driver inside your project repository in a folder (you can give any name to the folder, i have used "BrowserDriver"). Use below code for calling the driver:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/BrowserDriver/Mac/geckodriver 2");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Answer (score 1):

Many of you might get the error in creating path to geckodriver or firefox-driver it's very easy just follow this way:

```
from selenium import webdriver
path = "home/sysname/Desktop/geckodriver"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = path)
```

Notice that you have to write *executable_path=path*  and then give path variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a WebDriver that is an instance of Firefox, like so:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;


WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;//import this package
import org.openqa.selenium.By;        //import this package

WebDriver FF_river = new FirefoxDriver();//create a reference variable of FirefoxDriver() int
```

Comment: you should add an explanation along with your answer to explain why OP should implement your solution.

Comment: yes its require a webdriver for and instance to firefox, thats why you have to import these package and a reference variable

Comment: you didn't even use the packages you imported