# Nightwatch.js cannot start selenium server on Windows 8.1

Tags: java, selenium, nightwatch.js

[image: Nightwatch.json and terminal windows]

Nightwatch hangs when trying to start the selenium server.

Windows 8.1 / nightwatch@0.6.13

Attached are the images (clockwise) of

- Nightwatch.json file
- Terminal window showing the folders and java paths
- Starting the selenium server manually (no issues)
- Nightwatch starting selenium server... (hangs)

Any ideas on how to make nightwatch start selenium server successfully?

Thanks.

Update:
Upgraded nightwatch to 0.7.1
Updated nightwatch.json
selenium/cli_args contains
"-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver" : "C:/tools/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"
"-Dwebdriver.firefox.bin=" : "c:/code/nightwatch/Firefox/firefox.exe"

p.s. Copied Mozilla Firefox folder into nightwatch folder

Results:
Nightwatch running chrome works
Nightwatch running firefox throws

[image: Can't find firefox.exe]

Comment: Please paste the actual code and logs here rather than screenshots

Comment: @Alper - You'll probably have better luck with the NightwatchJS Google Group, which gets quick responses both from the library author, as well as many people in the community.   Worth signing up here - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/nightwatchjs

Looks like your particular issue may be due to "Driver class not found...OperaDriver" - Never tried to use Selenium with Opera before!

Comment: @geek_dave I'm not using Selenium with Opera, I get the same message when I start Selenium server manually and everything seems to work. Thanks for google group tip, signing up.

Answer (score 1):

- Upgraded nightwatch to 0.7.1
- Firefox is installed at C:\Users\{userName}\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox on my machine.
- In nightwatch.json, added the following setting to selenium / cli_args

  "-Dwebdriver.firefox.bin" : "C:/Users/{userName}/AppData/Local/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"

  Nightwatch starts selenium server, firefox and runs tests successfully.

For reference:
[Cannot find firefox binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950748/cannot-find-firefox-binary-in-path-make-sure-firefox-is-installed)