# PATH error visual studio Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to run a simple program but getting the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException'
>   occurred in WebDriver.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot find Firefox binary in PATH or default
>   install locations. Make sure Firefox is installed. OS appears to be:
>   Vista

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace selenium
{
    class Program
    {
           static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.reuters.com");
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            IWebElement searchInput = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//html/body/div[10]/div[3]/div/td[1]"));
            searchInput.GetAttribute("value").ToString();

            driver.Close();           

        }
    }
}
```

I checked the environment variables, and I have the following in the path:

> PATH=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe

I am currently running Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015 and selenium Webdriver 2.53.0

Comment: Windows `PATH` is a list of directories, not filenames. Try changing that to `PATH=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked like a charm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950748/cannot-find-firefox-binary-in-path-make-sure-firefox-is-installed)

Answer (score 2):

Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed Solution for  C#.

```
var opt = new FirefoxOptions
{
    BrowserExecutableLocation = @"c:\program files\mozilla firefox\firefox.exe"
};
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(opt);
```