# How to add Firefox to Path for Cucumber and Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, cucumber-junit

I am using Conductor framework for Selenium. I am using Cucumber as JUnit test runner. 
I am using Firefox webdriver but unable to add Firefox binaries to path. If I add -Dwebdriver.Firefox.bin="path" as JVM argument cucumber throws error.  I also tried to add a static block to set System property. Still selenium couldn't find Firefox binaries.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950748/cannot-find-firefox-binary-in-path-make-sure-firefox-is-installed

Comment: I am not creating driver explicitly. Conductor does under the hood.