# Selenium WebDriver 2.53 - set Firefox executable path

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a project with WebDriver 2.53. I am not ready to move it to 3.x. I am running Windows 7. My code is in Java.

With Selenium WebDriver 2.53, latest Firefox is not supported. I need to supply it with Firefox 44. (45 esr fails most of the time in my experience). But a system-wide installation of an old version of Firefox triggers a corporate auto-update system.

There is a portable version of Firefox 44 that one can install anywhere without affecting the system-wide Firefox. But I would need to set WebDriver to use the Firefox executable at a certain path, not in C:\Program Files(x86)\Mozilla Firefox.

How do I set this path? I did search bit nothing I could find online works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
File pathToBinary = new File("C:\\user\\Programme\\FirefoxPortable\\App\\Firefox\\firefox.exe");
FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();       
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary,firefoxProfile);
```

This is taken directly from another Stack Overflow post and I have not tried the code.   [Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950748/cannot-find-firefox-binary-in-path-make-sure-firefox-is-installed/24891650#24891650)