# Unable to launch Firefox in selenium 3.0-beta3 with geckodriver 0.10 using Javascript with selenium's own sample

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

just want to learn Selenium testing beginning with it's own sample.
However, after everything is set up(Node.js, Selenium), when I want to use selenium-webdriver's own sample, it is not working:

This is the official code(name is google_search.js) provided by selenium:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
driver.findElement(By.name('btnG')).click();
driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
driver.quit();
```

This code is within `example` folder, in Node.js cmd, I cd to node_modules\selenium-webdriver\example, and put geckodriver in this folder, then run `node google_search.js`
Here's the result:

```
C:\Users\username\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2291
        throw error;
        ^

WebDriverError: Unable to parse new session response: {"error":"unknown error","
message":"Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default
 location, no 'firefox_binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on th
e command line"}
    at WebDriverError (C:\Users\username\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\err
or.js:27:10)
    at C:\Users\username\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:335:17
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (C:\Users\username\node_modules\selenium-webdriver
\lib\webdriver.js:366:24)
    at createGeckoDriver (C:\Users\username\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\fire
fox\index.js:497:27)
    at Driver (C:\Users\username\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\firefox\index.j
s:605:14)
    at Builder.build (C:\Users\username\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js
:557:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\username\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\exa
mple\google_search.js:44:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
From: Task: WebDriver.navigate().to(http://www.google.com/ncr)
    at Driver.schedule (C:\Users\username\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\we
bdriver.js:414:17)
    at Navigation.to (C:\Users\username\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webd
river.js:1042:25)
    at Driver.get (C:\Users\username\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriv
er.js:832:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\username\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\exa
mple\google_search.js:46:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
```

Did I do anything wrong? Can anyone tell me why the offical sample is not launching firefox? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907492/how-to-get-firefox-working-with-selenium-webdriver-on-mac-osx - check this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error-message when trying to run a C#-application with Selenium 3.0.0.

The problem was that I was using the x64 Geckodriver.exe. After downloading and copying the 32bit version to my bin-folder, everything worked well.

-Robert