# selenium web driver : Able to open Firefox browser but unable to load Url

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, windows-7

While executing my script, script is able to open browser but it is not able to put url I used driver.get() method. Then I tried adding and increasing sleep time, after that my script is able to load url and it is working as expected but most of the time it is failing I don't know it is time problem or driver problem please suggest me proper solution.

Platform used - Windows 7
language -java
tool - selenium web driver 2.48.2
Firefox -34.0

code used for driver instance creation is as below :

```
try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        driver.get(myurl);
        }
```

error logs are as follows:

```
Slenium web driver : Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output...and ...Receiving org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH)
```

Comment: I am fetching myurl value from csv file

Comment: please try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950748/cannot-find-firefox-binary-in-path-make-sure-firefox-is-installed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Firefox working with Selenium WebDriver on Mac OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907492/how-to-get-firefox-working-with-selenium-webdriver-on-mac-osx)

Comment: Should the driver.get statement be in the catch block?

Comment: solved issue by recursively calling above try catch in function

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue i.e was unable to load baseurl in the browser... you need to replace

System.setProperty("**webdriver.gecko.driver**","C:\Marionette\geckodriver_1.exe" ); instead of
System.setProperty("**webdriver.firefox.marionette**","C:/Users/admin/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.11.1-win32/geckodriver.exe");

or try reverse